# Autofill down variable number of rows in a macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, excel-auto-fill

Here is a mock version of my data. There are two worksheets:

[image: 1]

and

[image: 2]

Column A is a TEXTJOIN function. The rest is filled in manually with the exception of the year. I want to get the year by using a FILTER function on the second worksheet. So, the function looks up the code in Column A on Sheet 1 in Column A on Sheet 2 and returns all of the years that are available for that code. In my data, the number of years is highly variable, which is why I have to go to such great lengths to automate this process.

In order to prevent spill errors, I already have a simple macro that copies a version of the FILTER function from the helper column labelled "MACRO". That one works fine, and it gives me all of the dates. However, I then want to autofill in the remaining information.

Demonstration:

When I run the first macro I get this result

[image]

I want a follow-up macro to give me this result:

[image]

So that I can simply run the first macro again and keep going. Because the cells that are spilled over from the FILTER function are not really filled in the conventional way, I think this problem is slightly more complicated than it otherwise would be. I think there needs to be a step in between the two macros where I autofill one of the columns myself so that all the other columns know how far to fill down.

Can anyone help me figure out the follow-up macro that will give me the result I want? I tried stuff with double clicking the autofill button but I still got messed up results. **Also note: Every column needs to be copied exactly when it gets autofilled, with the exception of the MACRO column with the FILTER function and the CODE column with the TEXTJOIN function, both of which need to have relative references. In my actual data set, some of the columns I want to autofill will think there is a pattern and will change an important number that needs to remain static.**

As a final thing, I also want the last macro to iterate the NUMBER column on the final row. In my example, I iterated it upward, but in my actual spreadsheet I want the analogous column to iterate downward.

Comment: You seem to just be replicating the data from one sheet onto another. That doesn't make sense. Why don't you return all four columns with `FILTER` instead of just the years?

Comment: The example is simple because I didn't want to spend any time on it and I didn't want to share any personally identifiable information. Trust me when I say that in context, these macros would save days of work.

Comment: Long story short: I have some items for which I know several data points. Each item has a certain number of additional data points associated with it (e.g., this laptop model was sold during these particular years). I imported a second worksheet that had the additional data points but tons of other stuff as well. I want to be able to enter in the few data points I know on my main sheet and then get a row for each of the extra data points (in my example, that would be a row for each year the laptop was sold). I know of no other way to do this fast.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it would be easier for you to just join the first sheet to the second on Code using PowerQuery.

Suppose I start here:

[image]

I want to "enhance" my data with the extra information from the supplementary data.

First I create a query on both tables by selecting any cell in the data range and using Data>Get & Transform Data>From Table/Range.

After doing that, I have two queries:

[image]

I select the first one, then use Home>Combine>Merge Queries>Merge Queries As New from the Power Query Editor Ribbon:

[image]

I configure the dialog like this, being sure to select the code column in each table and set the join kind to "left outer" (this ensures that my data will always show in the result, whether or not there's supplementary data for that franchise.

[image]

When I click OK, I see this:

[image]

I click the double-headed arrow at the top of the new column that's named "Table3" and configure it like this:

[image]

This expands the joined data so that I now have this:

[image]

Now I can click Home>Close & Load to put the results into the workbook.

Whenever new data is added to "My data" or to "Supplementary data", I can just right-click the query result and use "Refresh".

[image]

Comment: Very interesting, thanks! Unfortunately, I am not familiar with those functions of Excel, and I have to stay on task at work as much as possible, so I can't put in the time to learn them right now. I will try to figure out your suggestion when I get home tonight. In the meantime, if someone has a simpler solution that fits into the process I am currently using, I would love to hear about it!